# How to use a regular query on a 2d or 2dsphere indexed field with MongoDB 2.4

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, geospatial

I have a geospatial mongodb with legacy co-ordinate pair as Geo2D index. From this database I want to extract a list of locations (legacy co-ordinate pairs). For normal columns I can use a "$in" query over a list of possible pairs as below.

```
>>> db.collection.find_one({'country': {'$in': ['Argentina', 'Chile']}})
```

I am not sure how to do this over the loc column. Similar operation on the loc column throws an error

```
>>> db.collection.find_one({'loc': {'$in': [(-35, 20), (-30, 21)]}})

geo field only has 1 element :: caused by :: $in: [ [ -35, 20 ], [ -30, 21 ] ]
```

The solution i have in mind is to match each member of the list separately. However its probably not the most effective solution. Is there an aggregation/map-reduce trick I can do?

**Relevant Information**

The db looks like:

```
>>> db.collection.find_one()

{u'value': 2.7062699269224995,
 u'_id': ObjectId('56cf807e54013b935b88d3da'),
 u'country': u'Algeria',
 u'date': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 u'iso2': u'DZ',
 u'lat': 27.0,
 u'loc': [27.0, -8.0],
 u'lon': -8.0,
 u'place': u'27.0_-8.0_DZ'}
```

The index keys are:

```
[ { "_id" : 1 }, { "date" : -1 }, { "loc" : "2d" } ]
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the query you are actually running here? There is nothing "geospatial" about it as it should just be a regular match on arrays that "exactly" match the given arguments. Which MongoDB server version is this? It might be possible that anything prior to 2.6.x is getting "confused" as to how to handle the index, since the engine had major changes in that release.

Comment: The index is geospatial as I still want to do  $near queries. To rephrase my questiions its a $in query on a 2d index. This is mongodb 2.4.9

Comment: The point I was making was since you are using MongoDB 2.4 there is a difference in the query engine handling that causes the error.

Comment: Thanks Neil. Saw your answer as well. I will try it out and let you know

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the server version is a MongoDB 2.4.x series. Prior to MongoDB 2.6.x the query engine handling for "geospatial" indexes was done separately to standard queries, and as such by asking for a regular [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) expression as opposed to a geospatial operation such as [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/), the query is occurring in a part of the engine that cannot handle the expression since the field has a `"2d"` geospatial index applied.

So MongoDB 2.4.x "cannot" use a geospatial index with a regular query operation. If you "need" to use an "index" for your query, you "must" create a regular index using [`.ensure_index()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.ensure_index) on the field being referenced in the query:

```js
db.collection.ensure_index({ "loc": 1 })
```

Note that this is in "addition" to the "2d" index that is already applied. Since the indexes are of different "types", they are named and exist separately. So there is no problem having both.

The alternate is to [`.hint()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.hint) on the cursor with the [`$natural`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/) specifier to force a "collection scan" and therefore "ignore" the geospatial index.

From MongoDB 2.6.x and onwards, the query engine is unified and the restriction here does not apply. Depending on the query given the "geospatial" index may possibly not be used unless you again specify [`.hint()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.hint) in order to explicitly select that index for usage. But it will then work without problem.

As a final note, MongoDB 2.6.x and onwards allows the "geospatial" index to be created on data stored in GeoJSON format. i.e:

```js
"location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [27.0, -8.0]
}
```

Since such an index would be on the `"location"` field in this example and not directly on the `"location.coordinates"` array, such an [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) query would not recognise the "index" on `"location"` as being available for a normal query matching the array content. In this case you would again create a normal index directly on `"location.coordinates"` to allow a query to use that "index".

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the very detailed explanation. These are excellent points - especially for a new inductee like myself. I would try the `hint` method you proposed.